# tf.nn.conv2d_transpose() double width and height for dynamic shapes of input tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

When I tried to use **tf.nn.conv2d_transpose()** to get layer result which has doubled width, height and halved depth, it worked while using specified **[batch, width, height, channel(input and output)].**

By setting **batch_size="None",** training works well for specified batch_size and validation works well for images(or an image).

Now, I'm trying to make encoder-decoder network structure using training **[128 x 128 x 3]** images. (Those training images are cropped images from **[w x h x 3]** original images)

Input shape is **[128 x 128 x 3]** and output shape is **[128 x 128 x 3]**. First layer is convolution layer with k=3x3, strides = 1, padding = 1 with encoder-decoder structure.

All of the process above works well for specified width and height (128 x 128).

However, after training is finished with training patches of **[128 x 128 x 3]**, I'd like to infer **[w x h x 3]** image using trained network.

I guess all of the sequences : convolution, maxpool gives correct results, except transpose convolution.

When I infer fixed shape of images **[128 x 128 x 3]** :

```
InputImagesTensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 128, 128, 3], name='InputImages')
ResultImages = libs.Network(InputImagesTensor)
saver = tf.train.Saver()
w = 128
h = 128

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
saver.restore(sess, 'output.ckpt')
for i in range(0, len(Datas.InputImageNameList)):
    temp = np.resize(getResizedImage(Datas.InputImageList[i]), (1, 128, 128, 3))
    resultimg = sess.run(ResultImages, feed_dict={InputImagesTensor: temp})
```

with network inside :

```
def Transpose2d(input, inC, outC):
    b, w, h, c = input.shape

    batch_size = tf.shape(input)[0]
    deconv_shape = tf.stack([batch_size, int(w*2), int(h*2), outC])
    kernel = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 2, outC, inC], stddev=0.01))
    output_shape = [None, int(w * 2), int(h * 2), outC]
    transConv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(input, kernel, output_shape=deconv_shape, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding="SAME")

    return transConv
```

Now, I tried to convert them with fixed width and height to dynamic width and height.
In my opinion, this would work (however it failed)

Change

```
InputImagesTensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 128, 128, 3], name='InputImages')
temp = np.resize(getResizedImage(Datas.InputImageList[i]), (1, 128, 128, 3))
```

to

```
InputImagesTensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, None, None, 3], name='InputImages')
temp = np.resize(getResizedImage(Datas.InputImageList[i]), (1, w, h, 3))
```

However, this line gives error.

```
deconv_shape = tf.stack([batch_size, int(w*2), int(h*2), outC])
```

**TypeError: **int** returned non-int (type NoneType)**

I guess it is because we cannot double the **None** value to **2*None**.

How can I do this?? is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

Self answer...

I cannot come up with suitable 'standard' solution to set w, h as None property for transpose convolution.

However I solved problem by giving transpose convolution's shape as maximum shape of my training/validation images. For example, if the maximum width and height of my images = [656 x 656], and a test image = [450 x 656], then I create zeros np.ndarray of [656 x 656] and just fill [450 x 656] region using test image RGB. (Apply concept of zero-padding)